# calculating cumulatives within a group correctly

Tags: r, cumsum

I hope anyone can help with this. I have a data frame similar to this:

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(1:24),
                  group = rep(c(1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2),2),
                  year1 = rep(c(2018,2018,2018,2019,2019,2019),4),
                  month1 = rep(c(1,2,3),8))
```

Now I want to do a cumsum per group but when I use the following code the sumsum 'restarts' each year.

```
test2 <-test %>% 
  group_by(group,year1,month1) %>% 
  summarise(a = length(unique(ID)))  %>%
  mutate(a = cumsum(a))
```

My desired output is:

```
   group year1 month1  a
1      1  2018      1  2
2      1  2018      2  4
3      1  2018      3  6
4      1  2019      1  8
5      1  2019      2 10
6      1  2019      3 12
7      2  2018      1  2
8      2  2018      2  4
9      2  2018      3  6
10     2  2019      1  8
11     2  2019      2 10
12     2  2019      3 12
```

Comment: How is `a` cumsum of any value ?

Comment: @Ronak Shah. I want to have the total number of IDs for each group cumulative over month/year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first count unique `ID` for each `group`, `month` and `year` and then take `cumsum` of it for each `group`.

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  group_by(group, year1, month1) %>%
  summarise(a = n_distinct(ID)) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(a = cumsum(a)) 

#   group year1 month1     a
#   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
# 1     1  2018      1     2
# 2     1  2018      2     4
# 3     1  2018      3     6
# 4     1  2019      1     8
# 5     1  2019      2    10
# 6     1  2019      3    12
# 7     2  2018      1     2
# 8     2  2018      2     4
# 9     2  2018      3     6
#10     2  2019      1     8
#11     2  2019      2    10
#12     2  2019      3    12
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the following error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'double'. Do you know what may be the cause?

Comment: @Joep_S Are you using it on the same data as you have posted ? If not, does it work for the data that you have posted in your question ?

Comment: Both for the data I posted and for my original data

Comment: That is strange since it works for me. Can you restart R and try this on a fresh session with only `dplyr` loaded and check the results ? Moreover, also use `dplyr:: mutate` instead of just `mutate` to make sure you are using function from right package.

Comment: Still the same error after restart and using dplyr::mutate.

Comment: Got it working technically by changing cumsum(n)) to cumsum(a)) but now the numbers are not correct anymore

Comment: ooops..yeah. That should be `a`. Does it work on the sample provided? How is your data different the one shared ?

Comment: Numbers for the posted data are not correct either. I still get an ID column (which I don't want) and max(a) = 24 which is too high

Comment: @Joep_S Can you edit your post to show the complete expected output for the given example ? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: The desired output is already mentioned in the post (at the bottom). So basically, I don't want to have the ID column anymore since they are already counted in column 'a'

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts! It seems to work on my actual data to after some modifications (more columns to take into account)

Comment: you are welcome, sorry to waste your time. I did a very small mistake in understanding and it led up to this long series of conversation to and fro and I am glad you were able to solve this on your real data :)

Answer (score 0):

With `data.table`, this can be done with

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, .(a = uniqueN(ID)), by = .(group, year1, month1)
        ][, a := cumsum(a), by = group]
```